# Lista de checkbox seleciona somente a primeira opção não permitindo selecionar as demais

Tags: php, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário onde o mesmo possui uma lista de opções utilizando o input type checkbox. Ocorre que na lista de opções checkbox só e possível selecionar apenas a primeira opção não sendo possível selecionar as demais opções. Criei uma página de exemplo para demonstrar a minha dúvida: https://2020x.000webhostapp.com/post05/

No caso eu possuo uma tabela no MySql chamada **opcoes_tbl** onde a mesma possui uma coluna chamada **caracteristica** conforme estrutura abaixo:

**opções_tbl**

```
id | caracteristica
---------------------
01 | Aceita financiamento
02 | Aceita permuta
03 | Adega
xx | ...
```

No caso eu consigo pegar todos os dados da coluna **"caracteristica"** e explana-los em uma página sob o formato **input type checkbox** utilizando o código PHP e HTML abaixo:

```html
<div class="container">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">

        <?php

include 'dbConfig.php';
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM opcoes_tbl ORDER BY caracteristica ASC');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php foreach($results as $row):?>

      <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="opcoes" name="caracteristica" value="<?= $row['caracteristica']; ?>">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"><?= $row['caracteristica']; ?></label>
      </div>

<?php endforeach ?>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Porém, só é possível selecionar a primeira opção não sendo possível selecionar as demais opções conforme mencionado acima e demonstrado nesta página: https://2020x.000webhostapp.com/post05/. No caso, como faço para editar o código php para que o mesmo mostre todas as opções da coluna bem como dar a possibilidade do usuário selecionar mais de uma opção? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que todas as `labels` estão referenciando o mesmo `id`.

Tente assim:

```
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="<?= $row['id']; ?>" name="caracteristica" value="<?= $row['caracteristica']; ?>">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['caracteristica']; ?></label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show de bola Pedro. Era isso mesmo. Valeu, obrigado!